# Перебор значений JSON PHP

Tags: php, json

Есть два запроса в формате JSON:

1. `{"results":[{"header":{"similarity":"93.49"},"data":{"material":"azur lane"}}]}`
2. `{"results":[{"header":{"similarity":"93.49"},"data":{"material":"fate\/grand order, fate (series)"}}]}`

Так же есть код:

```
$sau_query = explode(", ", $sau_res->data->material);
$text = "";
foreach($sau_query as $value){


    if($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `tags_copyright` WHERE `first` LIKE '%{$value}%'")){

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
            $last = str_replace(' ', '_', ucwords(preg_replace('![^\w\d\s]*!', '', $value)));
            mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `tags_copyright` VALUES (NULL, '$value', '#$last')");
        }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){
            while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                if($res['last'] != ""){
                    $text .= $res['last']." ";
                    echo $res['last'] //(выдает #Azur_lane и #Fate_Series)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $text //(Выдает #Azur_lane Azur_lane #Fate_Series)
```

Не могу понять как так получается что на выходе дублируется #Azur_Lane

И как решить данную проблему? Заранее спасибо...

PS.

```
azur lanearray(6) {

    [0]=> string(1) "3" 

    ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 

    [1]=> string(9) "azur lane" 

    ["first"]=> string(9) "azur lane" 

    [2]=> string(10) "#Azur_Lane" 

    ["last"]=> string(10) "#Azur_Lane" 

} fate/grand order, 
fate (series)array(6) 

    { [0]=> string(2) "20" 

    ["id"]=> string(2) "20" 

    [1]=> string(16) "fate/grand order" 

    ["first"]=> string(16) "fate/grand order" 

    [2]=> string(0) "" 

    ["last"]=> string(0) "" 

} array(6) { 

    [0]=> string(1) "2" 

    ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 

    [1]=> string(13) "fate (series)" 

    ["first"]=> string(13) "fate (series)" 

    [2]=> string(12) "#Fate_Series" 

    ["last"]=> string(12) "#Fate_Series" 

}
```

Comment: А где Ваша инициализация `$text` происходит? Может, в цикл переменная приходит уже не пустой?

Comment: `$text` изначально пустая, а присвоение значения происходит только в данном участке кода. Нигде более она не появляется и тем более не меняет своё значение...

Comment: Приложите `var_dump($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: @mully, добавил в вопрос.

Comment: @Тимофей Кучербаев, я отформатировал ваш вывод. Думаю вы увидите почему у вас все повторяется

Answer (score 1):

В общем, вы используете `mysqli_fetch_array()`, по умолчанию, она возвращает вам массив  в виде `key => value`, а также `0 => value`, потому что вы не указали каким образом вы хотите видеть итоговый результат в переменной `$res`. Используйте второй параметр, чтобы указать что вы хотите использовать ***ассоциативный*** массив:

```php
$res = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Подробнее обо всех параметрах и примерах можете прочесть в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php). Как раз таки там и написано, что по умолчанию вам приходит массив с разными ключами, но дублирующимися значениями.

Comment: Пробовал, но проблема осталась. Попробовал добавить 3 JSON запрос. В итоге у меня дублируется 1 и 2 запросы.

Выглядит это так: 1. `Azur` 
2. `Azur` `Fate`
3. `Azur` `Fate` `World`
Так как у меня идет перебор, скорее всего из-за этого и дублируется. Пробовал очищать результаты перемененных но толкового ничего не вышло. Это если выводить переменную `$text`, а если вывести `$res['last'] то получается все как нужно, без повторов.

Comment: Психанул... И убрал `$text` и все стало "ок"... Последующее выполнение скрипта продолжил в том месте где переменной `$text`присваивается значение. Альтернативы пока не вижу.